# HTML & JQuery: how to add array to displayBox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I am creating an IPad application using JavaScript and Html. Html for the page design and JavaScript for the functionality. I have a displayBox created using Html and I want to populate this with an array of countries using javascript.

It is currently adding just the first item in the array to the displayBox but the following error is appearing when i debug the application using firefox

EDIT:

I got it working, i had to take off the end of it

BEFORE:

```
$('#countrySelection').append('<option value="' + this.id + '">' + this.name + '</option>').selectmenu('refresh');
```

AFTER

```
$('#countrySelection').append('<option value="' + this.id + '">' + this.name + '</option>');
```

the .selectmenu('refresh') was causing the error

Comment: Doesn't make any sense populating it using JS if it is gonna be static content anyways.

Comment: what do you suggest, populating it straight from the HTML page so is it?

Comment: Sure. From the information you have provided there is no evidence to require JS to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I have made some updates like adding $(document).ready() handler etc.

```
var arrayOfCountries = [{"name":"USA","id":1,"active":"Y"},{"name":"CANADA","id":2,"active":"Y"},{"name":"AALAND ISLANDS","id":270,"active":"Y"},{"name":"AFGHANISTAN","id":236,"active":"Y"},{"name":"ALBANIA","id":109,"active":"Y"},{"name":"ALGERIA","id":17,"active":"Y"},{"name":"AMERICAN SAMOA","id":307,"active":"Y"},{"name":"AMMAN","id":111,"active":"Y"},{"name":"ANDORRA","id":112,"active":"Y"},{"name":"ANGOLA","id":54,"active":"Y"},{"name":"ANGUILLA","id":22,"active":"Y"},{"name":"ANTARTICA","id":308,"active":"Y"},{"name":"ANTIGUA","id":113,"active":"Y"}];

$(document).ready(function(){

if ( $('#countrySelection').find('option').length == 0 ){

    $.loadingMessage = "Retrieving Countries";
    $.showPageLoadingMsg();

        $.each(arrayOfCountries, function() {
            $('#countrySelection').append('<option value="' + this.id + '">' + this.name + '</option>');//.selectmenu('refresh');
        });
       $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
}

});​
```

Comment: and how exactly is the     $(document).ready(function() linked to the form i am loading? is it by using the $('#countrySelection')?